# How to draw stripes in python pillow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have made a stripes as you can see in folowing code. I was wondering is there a simplest way to do this? or some other way that you can think of, if there are, please provide code.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.line((100, 10, 0, 10), (0, 0, 0), 10)
draw.line((100, 30, 0, 30), (0, 0, 0), 10)
draw.line((100, 50, 0, 50), (0, 0, 0), 10)
draw.line((100, 70, 0, 70), (0, 0, 0), 10)
draw.line((100, 90, 0, 90), (0, 0, 0), 10)
img.show()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is no simpler way but you can use `for`-loop to make shorter code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simpler way but you can use `for`-loop to make shorter code.

```
for y in range(10, 91, 20):
    draw.line((100, y, 0, y), (0, 0, 0), 10)
```

Comment: Ok, good to know. Thanks!